# MVC3 ajax return new view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have some code which displays a dropbox with a list of entries from a database and calls a controller action on the `change` event. The controller takes the selected entry as a string and returns a new view (I think herein lies my issue), the trouble is I think that the old view still remains as the newly returned view is never displayed.

Do I need to redesign this or if not, should I be forcibly destroying any old view?

My code is as follows:

`EditSchool` view:

```
@model namespace.Models.SchoolDetails
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditSchool";
    Layout = "~/Views/AuthorisedAdmin/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bubble-popup-chosen-upload-functions.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#School").change(function () {
            var SelectedSchool = $('#School').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/AuthorisedAdmin/RetrieveSchool'
                , type: 'POST'
                , data: { School: SelectedSchool }
                , success: function (data) {
                }
                , error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown.toString());
                }
                , complete: function (request, textStatus) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Select School</legend>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("School", ViewBag.RegisteredSchools as SelectList, namespace.Models.Helpers.LanguageSchoolsConstants.m_sDropdownDisplayText,
            new
            {
                id = "School",
                @class = "chosen",
            })
    </div>
</fieldset>

@{
    if (null != Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("Partial/EditSchoolPartial", Model)
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.Partial("Partial/NoSchoolSelected")
    }    
}
```

Note that the partial view (`EditSchoolPartial`) is probably not a concern here, so I'm not posting the code.

Controller methods of interest:

`EditSchool` action:

```
public ActionResult EditSchool()
{
    List<string>kRegisteredSchools = DBHelperFunctionsSchool.Instance().GetRegisteredSchoolsNamesOnly();
    ViewBag.RegisteredSchools = new SelectList(kRegisteredSchools, "Name");
    SchoolDetails schoolDetails = null;//DBHelperFunctionsSchool.Instance().GetSchoolDetailsForName(kRegisteredSchools.FirstOrDefault());
    return View(schoolDetails);
}
```

`RetrieveSchool` action (called by AJAX):

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RetrieveSchool(string School)
    {
        SchoolDetails schoolDetails = null;
        List<string> kRegisteredSchools = DBHelperFunctionsSchool.Instance().GetRegisteredSchoolsNamesOnly();
        ViewBag.RegisteredSchools = new SelectList(kRegisteredSchools, "Name");

        try
        {
            schoolDetails = new SchoolDetails();
            schoolDetails.School = DBHelperFunctionsSchool.Instance().GetSchoolForName(School);
            DBHelperFunctionsSchool.Instance().PopulateSchoolDetailsSuppData(schoolDetails);
            schoolDetails.ActionNameToExecuteOnFormSubmit = "EditSchoolDetails";
            schoolDetails.ControllerNameToExecuteOnFormSubmit = "AuthorisedAdmin";
        }
        catch
        {
            schoolDetails = null;
        }
        finally
        {
        }

        return View("EditSchool", schoolDetails);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect to your view on ajax hit to your controller?

Comment: Yes - If by this you mean, user changes dropdown selection, controller then queries the selection and returns a new view with the relevant selections data? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing ajax on onchange ,do below

```
 $("#School").change(function () {
       var SelectedSchool = $('#School').val();
       window.location='/AuthorisedAdmin/RetrieveSchool?School='+SelectedSchool;
  });
```

Note:You may have to give full path url instead of relative url.

Comment: Thank you. I have since realized that my whole idea is fundamentally wrong as I am trying to use Ajax to do a job that it is not designed to do. I appreciate your input though and your solution is spot on for my purposes. Thanks